# Error in installing uWSGI + lua plugin

Tags: lua, uwsgi

I am trying to install the uWSGI and lua plugin using this command:

**curl http://uwsgi.it/install | bash -s lua /tmp/uwsgi**

but I am getting following error :

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_luaL_loadfile", referenced from:
      _uwsgi_lua_code_string in lua_plugin.o
      _uwsgi_lua_app in lua_plugin.o
  "_luaL_loadstring", referenced from:
      _uwsgi_lua_configurator in lua_plugin.o
  "_luaL_newstate", referenced from:
      _uwsgi_lua_code_string in lua_plugin.o
      _uwsgi_lua_app in lua_plugin.o
      _uwsgi_lua_configurator in lua_plugin.o
  "_luaL_openlibs", referenced from:
      _uwsgi_lua_code_string in lua_plugin.o
      _uwsgi_lua_app in lua_plugin.o
      _uwsgi_lua_configurator in lua_plugin.o
  "_luaL_ref", referenced from:
      _uwsgi_api_register_signal in lua_plugin.o
      _uwsgi_api_register_rpc in lua_plugin.o
  "_luaL_register", referenced from:
      _uwsgi_lua_app in lua_plugin.o
  "_lua_close", referenced from:
      _uwsgi_lua_code_string in lua_plugin.o
      _uwsgi_lua_configurator in lua_plugin.o
  "_lua_createtable", referenced from:
      _uwsgi_lua_request in lua_plugin.o
  "_lua_error", referenced from:
      _uwsgi_api_log in lua_plugin.o
      _uwsgi_api_websocket_handshake in lua_plugin.o
      _uwsgi_api_websocket_recv in lua_plugin.o
      _uwsgi_api_websocket_recv_nb in lua_plugin.o
      _uwsgi_api_websocket_send in lua_plugin.o
      _uwsgi_api_websocket_send_from_sharedarea in lua_plugin.o
      _uwsgi_api_websocket_send_binary in lua_plugin.o
      ...
  "_lua_gc", referenced from:
      _uwsgi_lua_request in lua_plugin.o
  "_lua_getfield", referenced from:
      _uwsgi_lua_hijack in lua_plugin.o
      _uwsgi_lua_code_string in lua_plugin.o
  "_lua_gettable", referenced from:
      _uwsgi_lua_app in lua_plugin.o
  "_lua_gettop", referenced from:
      _uwsgi_api_log in lua_plugin.o
      _uwsgi_api_cache_get in lua_plugin.o
      _uwsgi_api_cache_set in lua_plugin.o
      _uwsgi_api_cache_update in lua_plugin.o
      _uwsgi_api_cache_del in lua_plugin.o
      _uwsgi_api_cache_exists in lua_plugin.o
      _uwsgi_api_cache_clear in lua_plugin.o
      ...
  "_lua_isnumber", referenced from:
      _uwsgi_api_lock in lua_plugin.o
      _uwsgi_api_unlock in lua_plugin.o
      _uwsgi_lua_configurator in lua_plugin.o
  "_lua_isstring", referenced from:
      _uwsgi_lua_code_string in lua_plugin.o
      _uwsgi_api_log in lua_plugin.o
      _uwsgi_api_cache_get in lua_plugin.o
      _uwsgi_api_cache_del in lua_plugin.o
      _uwsgi_api_cache_exists in lua_plugin.o
  "_lua_next", referenced from:
      _uwsgi_lua_request in lua_plugin.o
      _uwsgi_lua_configurator in lua_plugin.o
  "_lua_objlen", referenced from:
      _uwsgi_lua_configurator in lua_plugin.o
  "_lua_pcall", referenced from:
      _uwsgi_lua_request in lua_plugin.o
      _uwsgi_lua_hijack in lua_plugin.o
      _uwsgi_lua_signal_handler in lua_plugin.o
      _uwsgi_lua_code_string in lua_plugin.o
      _uwsgi_lua_rpc in lua_plugin.o
      _uwsgi_lua_app in lua_plugin.o
      _uwsgi_lua_configurator in lua_plugin.o
      ...
  "_lua_pushboolean", referenced from:
      _uwsgi_api_cache_set in lua_plugin.o
      _uwsgi_api_cache_update in lua_plugin.o
      _uwsgi_api_cache_del in lua_plugin.o
      _uwsgi_api_cache_exists in lua_plugin.o
      _uwsgi_api_cache_clear in lua_plugin.o
      _uwsgi_api_register_rpc in lua_plugin.o
      _uwsgi_api_is_connected in lua_plugin.o
      ...
  "_lua_pushcclosure", referenced from:
      _uwsgi_lua_request in lua_plugin.o
  "_lua_pushlstring", referenced from:
      _uwsgi_lua_request in lua_plugin.o
      _uwsgi_lua_code_string in lua_plugin.o
      _uwsgi_lua_rpc in lua_plugin.o
      _uwsgi_api_cache_get in lua_plugin.o
      _uwsgi_api_websocket_recv in lua_plugin.o
      _uwsgi_api_websocket_recv_nb in lua_plugin.o
      _uwsgi_lua_input in lua_plugin.o
      ...
  "_lua_pushnil", referenced from:
      _uwsgi_lua_request in lua_plugin.o
      _uwsgi_lua_code_string in lua_plugin.o
      _uwsgi_api_cache_get in lua_plugin.o
      _uwsgi_api_cache_set in lua_plugin.o
      _uwsgi_api_cache_update in lua_plugin.o
      _uwsgi_api_cache_del in lua_plugin.o
      _uwsgi_api_cache_exists in lua_plugin.o
      ...
  "_lua_pushnumber", referenced from:
      _uwsgi_lua_signal_handler in lua_plugin.o
      _uwsgi_api_req_fd in lua_plugin.o
      _uwsgi_api_async_connect in lua_plugin.o
      _uwsgi_api_ready_fd in lua_plugin.o
  "_lua_pushstring", referenced from:
      _uwsgi_lua_request in lua_plugin.o
      _uwsgi_lua_app in lua_plugin.o
      _uwsgi_api_log in lua_plugin.o
      _uwsgi_api_websocket_handshake in lua_plugin.o
      _uwsgi_api_websocket_recv in lua_plugin.o
      _uwsgi_api_websocket_recv_nb in lua_plugin.o
      _uwsgi_api_websocket_send in lua_plugin.o
      ...
  "_lua_pushvalue", referenced from:
      _uwsgi_lua_request in lua_plugin.o
      _uwsgi_lua_code_string in lua_plugin.o
      _uwsgi_api_register_signal in lua_plugin.o
      _uwsgi_api_register_rpc in lua_plugin.o
  "_lua_rawgeti", referenced from:
      _uwsgi_lua_signal_handler in lua_plugin.o
      _uwsgi_lua_rpc in lua_plugin.o
      _uwsgi_lua_configurator in lua_plugin.o
  "_lua_replace", referenced from:
      _uwsgi_lua_app in lua_plugin.o
  "_lua_setfield", referenced from:
      _uwsgi_lua_request in lua_plugin.o
      _uwsgi_lua_app in lua_plugin.o
  "_lua_settop", referenced from:
      _uwsgi_lua_request in lua_plugin.o
      _uwsgi_lua_code_string in lua_plugin.o
      _uwsgi_lua_rpc in lua_plugin.o
      _uwsgi_lua_configurator in lua_plugin.o
  "_lua_tolstring", referenced from:
      _uwsgi_lua_request in lua_plugin.o
      _uwsgi_lua_signal_handler in lua_plugin.o
      _uwsgi_lua_code_string in lua_plugin.o
      _uwsgi_lua_rpc in lua_plugin.o
      _uwsgi_lua_app in lua_plugin.o
      _uwsgi_api_log in lua_plugin.o
      _uwsgi_api_cache_get in lua_plugin.o
      ...
  "_lua_tonumber", referenced from:
      _uwsgi_api_cache_set in lua_plugin.o
      _uwsgi_api_cache_update in lua_plugin.o
      _uwsgi_api_register_signal in lua_plugin.o
      _uwsgi_api_websocket_send_from_sharedarea in lua_plugin.o
      _uwsgi_api_websocket_send_binary_from_sharedarea in lua_plugin.o
      _uwsgi_api_lock in lua_plugin.o
      _uwsgi_api_unlock in lua_plugin.o
      ...
  "_lua_type", referenced from:
      _uwsgi_lua_request in lua_plugin.o
      _uwsgi_lua_code_string in lua_plugin.o
      _uwsgi_lua_app in lua_plugin.o
      _uwsgi_lua_configurator in lua_plugin.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
*** error linking uWSGI ***

It would be very kind if you could take a look and suggests how to make it work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is it osx ? be sure to have a 64bit lua runtime

Comment: Yes it is OS X. I tried using the 64 bit lua runtime but still its giving me the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Download lua library tarball and decompress it in the uWSGI sources directory. Then instruct uwsgi to use that library:

UWSGICONFIG_LUAINC=include UWSGICONFIG_LUALIBPATH=. UWSGICONFIG_LUALIB=lua52 make lua

this is because you cannot rely on pkg-config on OSX.

Comment: I have cloned this "https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi" to my local machine for the uWSGI installation. But I am not able to find the  directory names "sources" to paste the decompressed lua tar ball.

Comment: ehm sources in the mean of project sources not "directory" :) just explode the liblua tarball into the git repos

Comment: I have tried installing using the option you have suggested and hitting this error : 

d -lm -lz -L/usr/local/Cellar/pcre/8.35/lib -lpcre -lssl -lcrypto -lxml2 -llua52
ld: library not found for -llua52
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
*** error linking uWSGI ***
make: *** [lua] Error 1

I have exploded the lua tar ball inside the sources of uWSGI. and Lua is also installed on my mac.

Comment: check if the path you specified in UWSGICONFIG_LUALIBPATH corresponds to the dir containing liblua52.dylib. Eventually change it accordingly (or change the libname if you are using another version)

Comment: we have run this command "python uwsgiconfig.py --plugin plugins/lua core" and got this output.

using profile: buildconf/core.ini
detected include path: ['/usr/local/include', '/usr/bin/../lib/clang/5.1/include', '/usr/include', '/System/Library/Frameworks', '/Library/Frameworks']
*** uWSGI building and linking plugin plugins/lua ***
[clang] ./lua_plugin.so
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-LTPL_PREFIX/lib'
build time: 0 seconds
*** lua plugin built and available in ./lua_plugin.so *** 
(please see next comment also)

Comment: we tried to start the uWSGI as "uwsgi --plugins lua --http :8080 --http-modifier1 6 --lua pippo.lua"

I am getting the following error. 
!!! UNABLE to load uWSGI plugin: dlopen(./lua_plugin.so, 10): Symbol not found: _uwsgi_is_connected
  Referenced from: ./lua_plugin.so
  Expected in: dynamic lookup
 !!!
uwsgi: unrecognized option `--lua'
getopt_long() error